# How can I upload a file from iOS to Cloudinary using expo-image-picker?

Tags: javascript, react-native, file-upload, expo, cloudinary

I'm using [expo](https://expo.io)/react-native, developing on MacOS, testing on the iOS emulator. Following various examples I keep getting 400s (invalid url, missing `file` parameter etc...) when I POST a file selected from the photo library to [Cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/). Unfortunately Cloudinary doesn't have very good documentation for react-native.

I also want to display a progress indicator so using `fetch()` is not an option.

I'm doing the uploads directly from the mobile app rather than passing through my server which is why Cloudinary's nodeJS docs don't apply. For security these upload requests will eventually be signed.

Answer (score 1):

This took way longer to figure out than I liked so I'm posting the solution here. The real key is that Cloudinary expects image data to be provided as `base64` from mobile whereas from the web a local file URL was sufficient. Fortunately the base64 data is available directly from the `expo-image-picker` component but it still must be formatted as a [data uri](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) to be uploaded.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import { ImageInfo } from 'expo-image-picker/build/ImagePicker.types';
import { Platform, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { CloudinaryImage } from './CloudinaryImage';

export const MyComponent = () => {
  const [cloudinaryId, setCloudinaryId] = useState('');
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(100);
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (Platform.OS !== 'web') {
        const { status } =
          await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
        if (status !== 'granted')
          alert('Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!');
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  return (progress === 100) ?
    (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={pickImage}>
        <CloudinaryImage cloudinaryId={cloudinaryId} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ) : ( ... a progress indicator of your choosing );
```

The `pickImage` function follows. This runs when the user touches the `TouchableOpacity` component.

```
const pickImage = async () => {
  const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
    mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
    allowsEditing: true,
    aspect: [1, 1],
    quality: 1,
    base64: true, // this must be set for base64 to be returned!
  });
  if (!result.cancelled) {
    const { uri, base64 } = result;
    cloudinaryUpload({ image: { uri, base64 }, setProgress, setCloudinaryId });
  }
};
```

The `cloudinaryUpload` function follows. This uses `XMLHttpRequest` instead of `fetch` in order to support progress.

```
const cloudName = 'yourCloud';
const uploadPreset = 'yourPreset';
const url = `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${cloudName}/upload`;

export const cloudinaryUpload = async ({ image, setProgress, setCloudinaryId }) => {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', url, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');

  // Update progress (can be used to show progress indicator)
  xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', (e) => {
    const progress = Math.round((e.loaded * 100.0) / e.total);
    setProgress(progress);
  });

  // handle successful upload
  xhr.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      setProgress(100);
      setCloudinaryId(response.public_id);
    }
  };

  xhr.addEventListener('error', (e) => console.error(e));

  const fd = new FormData();
  const data = `data:;base64,${image.base64}`; // the critical step!
  fd.append('file', data);
  fd.append('upload_preset', uploadPreset);
  fd.append('tags', 'your tags');
  setProgress(0);
  xhr.send(fd);
};
```

`<CloudinaryImage />` is just a component that renders a Cloudinary image based on its ID. The source to that component is the answer to a different question.

I have yet to try this on Android.